# How to move and branch team projects?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I'm looking for some assistance restructuring existing code in TFS. (I'm using TFS 2010 and don't have the option of upgrading.)

The current structure is as follows:

- Collection

  - Project 001
  - Project 002
  - Project 003
  - Project 004
  - Project 005

I would like to change the structure to the following (`Version100` would be a branch off `Main`, branched by the date version 1 was released.):

- Collection

  - Main

    - Project 001
    - Project 002
    - Project 003
    - Project 004
    - Project 005
  - Version100

    - Project 001
    - Project 002
    - Project 003
    - Project 004
    - Project 005

My first question is if my understanding is correct that all folders immediately below `Collection` must be team projects, and that all other folders must be regular folders? So I would need to convert those team projects to regular folders?

My second question is: is this even possible? Can you branch a team project? There doesn't appear to be any way to branch the contents of the folder immediately below `Collection`. I can't even select multiple items there. I know I can copy the files manually and then check them in, but I would lose all history. Also, it wouldn't be a true branch.

**UPDATE:**

It was suggested that I need to structure my folders one level deeper so that I'm branching a regular folder instead of a team project. But how can I do this without losing my history? And without my history, I wouldn't be able to create my version branch.

Comment: I would recommend against this. Microsoft is working towards isolating Team Projects more and more and cross team linking, branching and such are being hidden and made less and less available. Why not have Collection/Root/Main/* just everythign one level up.

Comment: Also: Upgrading may not be an option. TFS 2010 is in unsupported land, it's dependent SQL Server version and Windows version are going in the same direction.

Comment: @jessehouwing: When someone pays you to do something, you have to work within their constraints. So you're preaching to the choir but they are aware of the problem.

Comment: @jessehouwing: I'm open to your suggestion, but how can I do that without losing all my history? And without that history, I would have no way to branch by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Team Projects are special entities meant to provide **isolation**.

Think of each team project as containing a totally separate repository.

You should have **one** team project that contains all of your application's code and all of that application's branches.

- You cannot branch a team project -- you can branch folders contained **within** a team project.
- You cannot move code between team projects

If something is already isolated in a team project, there is no way to move it to another team project and retain its history. There's just no way.

Comment: Thanks. But so, basically, I can't do what I want? If I copy the files manually, it won't be a real branch. It will just be a duplicate of some of the code.

Comment: @JonathanWood You can create a branch and then check in the changes after it's created.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. How can I branch my collection to a subfolder this way?

Comment: You can't branch a collection. You need to create an appropriate trunk in one of your team projects. Then create a branch representing whatever version you're trying to maintain. Then copy the code that represents that version into the branch. Then commit the code.

Comment: Right, but I would copy it manually, right? So it isn't a real branch. And without history information, I wouldn't be able to create my version branch based on dates.

Comment: I have extracted the information for each branch. Is there any way to have TFS make that into a real branch, where the code is not duplicated in the repository?

Comment: This is a "to make an omelette, you need to break a few eggs" scenario. Any branch you make off of your new trunk *will* be a "real branch". You also just might have to abandon older branches and define a new strategy for branching that you will follow **going forward**, and leave the old stuff behind.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "a real branch". If you right-clicked and selected "Branch", then it's a real branch.

Comment: I know it will be a "branch". But how to make the contents branched? When you branch, TFS will not duplicate the code in the repository. It only stores the deltas. Is there any way to do that from files manually copied into that folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179940/discussion-between-daniel-mann-and-jonathan-wood).